# What is the difference between Flight Test and Test Flight?

Tags: terminology, flight-testing

What is the difference between *Test Flight* and *Flight Test*?
Are they the same thing or synonymous?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flight testing is the *process* (usually involving a number of test flights) by which the capabilities and performance of and aircraft (usually a new one or one which is substantially modified) are established.

Test flight refers to an *individual flight* which is used for testing purpose. it can be used either as part of flight testing or as a standalone for testing some minor modification.

Comment: A 'flight test' is also used when talking about assessing the pilot's competency, whereas I have never come across 'test flight' meaning the same.

Answer (score 0):

They are synonymous in the business.

Comment: the other answers disagrees and gives details. could you provide something more that shows how the two are synonyms?

Comment: Well ten years in the business of designing and flight testing aircraft would be the first one.  No one at an OEM is that distinct.